# multiple clients stop and wait with C & UDP

Tags: c, sockets

I am implementing stop&wait with c and udp socket programming. with one client it works but with more than one client it dosen't work.

server.c

```
struct sockaddr_in newAddr;
socklen_t addr_size = sizeof(newAddr);
fd_set rset;
int frame_id = 0;
Frame frame_recv;
Frame frame_send;

int socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

if (socket_desc < 0) {
    perror("Socket Creation Failed ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else {
    perror("Socket Created ");
}

if (bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr,
        sizeof(server_addr)) < 0 ) {
    perror("Bind Failed ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else {
    perror("Bind Done ");
}

printf("Listening for Messages...\n");

FD_ZERO(&rset);

while (1) {
    FD_SET(socket_desc, &rset);
    select(socket_desc + 1, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (FD_ISSET(socket_desc, &rset)) {
        int recv_size = recvfrom(socket_desc, &frame_recv, sizeof(Frame), 0,
                                  (struct sockaddr *) &newAddr, &addr_size);
        if (recv_size > 0 && frame_recv.frame_kind == 1 &&
            frame_recv.sq_no == frame_id) {
            printf("[+]Frame Received: %s\n", frame_recv.packet.data);

            frame_send.sq_no = 0;
            frame_send.frame_kind = 0;
            frame_send.ack = frame_recv.sq_no + 1;
            sendto(socket_desc, &frame_send, sizeof(frame_send), 0,
                  (struct sockaddr*)&newAddr, addr_size);
            printf("[+]Ack Send\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("[+]Frame Not Received\n");
            break;
        }
        frame_id ++;
    }
}
close(socket_desc);
```

client.c

```
char buffer[1024];
socklen_t addr_size;
int frame_id = 0;
Frame frame_send;
Frame frame_recv;
int ack_recv = 1;

int socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

if (socket_desc < 0) {
    perror("Socket Creation Failed ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else {
    perror("Socket Created ");
}

while (1) {
    if (ack_recv == 1) {
        frame_send.sq_no = frame_id;
        frame_send.frame_kind = 1;
        frame_send.ack = 0;

        printf("Enter Data: ");
        scanf("%s", buffer);
        strcpy(frame_send.packet.data, buffer);
        sendto(socket_desc, &frame_send, sizeof(Frame), 0,
              (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
        printf("[+]Frame Send\n");
    }
    int addr_size = sizeof(server_addr);
    int recv_size = recvfrom(socket_desc, &frame_recv, sizeof(frame_recv), 0 ,(struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, &addr_size);

    if (recv_size > 0 && frame_recv.sq_no == 0 && frame_recv.ack == frame_id + 1) {
        printf("[+]Ack Received\n");
        ack_recv = 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("[-]Ack Not Received\n");
        ack_recv = 0;
        break;
    }

    frame_id++;
}
close(socket_desc);
```

header.h

```
typedef struct packet {
    char data[1024];
} Packet;

typedef struct frame {
    int frame_kind; //ACK:0, SEQ:1 FIN:2
    int sq_no;
    int ack;
    Packet packet;
} Frame;
```

I found that `frame_recv.sq_no` and `frame_id` have different value when the second client run.

I read questions with same topic, but could not find out the error from my code.

Comment: `perror("Socket Created ");` Doesn't really make any sense.  If the `socket` call is successful, it does not necessarily leave `errno` in any particular value, and this may lead to confusing error messages like `Socket Created: not a typewriter`.  You really don't want to write an error message unless an error has occurred.

Comment: Thank you. I will fixed it. Would you please checked the code for the problem?